Fehler in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : Kontraste können nur auf Faktoren mit 2 oder mehr Stufen angewendet werden
I encountered a problem in R when trying to bootstrap my multiple regression with a continous variable as outcome and several variables as predictors (factors and numeric). When running , R throws the error
Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :    contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels 

The data, however, seem to be okay , also I don't have any NA in my dataset.
tibble [61 × 13] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ PTBS_Gesamt                        : num [1:61] 29 20 28 32 54 27 22 25 31 26 ...
 $ PHQ4_Gesamt                        : num [1:61] 10 5 6 7 7 10 5 5 7 7 ...
 $ Wohlbefinden_Gesamt                : num [1:61] 26 32 24 31 23 28 33 31 31 24 ...
 $ Erwartungen_Geburt_Gesamt          : num [1:61] -5 4 1 -5 2 2 2 9 -9 -1 ...
 $ Erwartungen_Zeit_nach_Geburt_Gesamt: num [1:61] 58 -6 9 21 -3 30 12 18 7 26 ...
 $ Objektive_Geburtserfahrung         : num [1:61] 1 0 1 2 2 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ Differenz_Geburtsort               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Keine Übereinstimmung",..: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DE09                               : num [1:61] 4 4 1 4 1 2 5 2 5 5 ...
 $ DE06                               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Ja1","Ja2": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DE07                               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Ja1","Ja2": 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ KV02                               : Factor w/ 2 levels "Ja1","Ja2": 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Wohlbefinden_Baseline              : num [1:61] 25 28 25 26 28 22 28 25 27 28 ...
 $ PHQ4_Baseline                      : num [1:61] 11 5 5 5 8 7 5 4 6 5 ...

But still it doesnt work...
> set.seed(12345)
> 
> model_PTBS_mk_b <- lm(data = joined_data_relevant, PTBS_Gesamt ~ Erwartungen_Geburt_Gesamt + Erwartungen_Zeit_nach_Geburt_Gesamt+ Objektive_Geburtserfahrung + Differenz_Geburtsort  + DE09 + KV02 + DE06 + DE07)
> fit_PTBS_mk_b <- Boot(model_PTBS_mk_b, R = 5000)
Fehler in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  Kontraste können nur auf Faktoren mit 2 oder mehr Stufen angewendet werden

Any ideas what goes wrong here?
and my session info:
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lmtest_0.9-40    zoo_1.8-12       boot_1.3-28.1    car_3.1-2        carData_3.0-5    psych_2.3.3      effectsize_0.8.6
 [8] ggpubr_0.6.0     lubridate_1.9.2  forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.0    purrr_1.0.1      readr_2.1.4      tibble_3.2.1    
[15] ggplot2_3.4.4    tidyverse_2.0.0  dplyr_1.1.2      tidyr_1.3.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.3       xfun_0.39          bayestestR_0.13.1  insight_0.19.7     rstatix_0.7.2      lattice_0.21-8    
 [7] tzdb_0.4.0         vctrs_0.6.2        tools_4.3.0        generics_0.1.3     datawizard_0.9.0   parallel_4.3.0    
[13] fansi_1.0.4        pkgconfig_2.0.3    lifecycle_1.0.3    compiler_4.3.0     munsell_0.5.0      mnormt_2.1.1      
[19] htmltools_0.5.5    yaml_2.3.7         crayon_1.5.2       pillar_1.9.0       abind_1.4-5        nlme_3.1-162      
[25] tidyselect_1.2.0   digest_0.6.31      mvtnorm_1.2-4      stringi_1.7.12     fastmap_1.1.1      grid_4.3.0        
[31] colorspace_2.1-0   cli_3.6.1          magrittr_2.0.3     utf8_1.2.3         broom_1.0.4        withr_2.5.0       
[37] scales_1.2.1       backports_1.4.1    bit64_4.0.5        timechange_0.2.0   estimability_1.4.1 rmarkdown_2.25    
[43] emmeans_1.8.9      bit_4.0.5          ggsignif_0.6.4     hms_1.1.3          evaluate_0.21      knitr_1.43        
[49] parameters_0.21.1  rlang_1.1.1        glue_1.6.2         rstudioapi_0.14    vroom_1.6.3        R6_2.5.1          
> 

I already bootstrapped the regression only with my main variables (the others are controlvariables)
there it worked just finde
model_PTBS_mk_b <- lm(data = joined_data_relevant, PTBS_Gesamt ~ Erwartungen_Geburt_Gesamt + Erwartungen_Zeit_nach_Geburt_Gesamt)

